# You have a syntax error in your SQL next to 'OVER (ORDER BY r.Id)) AS Grown FROM results AS r ORDER BY r.Id LIMIT 0.25' on line 1

Tags: mysql, math

I have a SQL command that lists the data in the table using lag to calculate with the previous value, to calculate the increase percentage. On my localhost it worked but on my hosting it keeps giving this error, I use mysql.

```
CREATE TABLE `results` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `grown` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Here is the command I used

```
SELECT 
    *, - 100.0 * ( 1-price/ LAG(price) OVER (ORDER BY results.id)) AS Grown 
FROM 
    results AS r 
ORDER BY 
    r.id;
```

Comment: You specified a floating-point value for `LIMIT`. This doesn't make sense. Did you mean `LIMIT 0, 25` perhaps?

Comment: @r3mainer yes its that

Answer (score 0):

You have “ OVER (ORDER BY t.Id))” but no table/alias called t

Comment: still the same error

Comment: it's strange that this only happens on my hosting on the local server it doesn't happen

Comment: @higashikata Check your versions window functions were introduced in version 8. also once aliased you cannot use full table name..

Comment: ok , Windows 8.0.13